# How to check if a user id exists in the array before adding?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 models (TweetModel and RatingModel), and I want to add new user IDs to array retweets that have RatingModel, but I need to check if a user id exists in the array before adding to DB.
I will be grateful for the answer

```
RatingModel.findByIdAndUpdate(tweetId, { $push: { retweets: user._id } }).exec(async (err) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(422).send()
      } else {
        res.json({
          status: 'successful retweet',
          data: await TweetModel.findById(tweetId),
        })
      }
    })
```

[RATING MODEL IN MONGODB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsyRF.png)

Comment: You could use $addToSet instead of $push.

Comment: use `findOneAndUpdate` with not equal to condition, `findOneAndUpdate({ _id: tweetId, "retweets": { $ne: user._id } }, ....`

Comment: I just found a method exists(). Seems to work fine. Can i use it? `const isExist = await RatingModel.exists({ _id: tweetId, retweets: user._id })` //true or false